# How can an object get destroyed through the camera sight?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been having some trouble making the player get destroyed through the camera. In my application, I made the camera follow the player(the ball). But the camera can only follow the ball upwards. So what I want to accomplish is, when the player(the ball) reaches the bottom of the interface(the screen) it gets destroyed. After it gets destroyed it would be good, if a new activity(new screen) pops up, that says "Game over". Thanks a lot for the great support. Please take a look at the [interface of the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIFxy.png)

```
package com.luca.tuninga;

 import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
 import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;


public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {


public static float APP_FPS = 60f;
public static int V_WIDTH = 480;
public static int V_HEIGHT = 640;


Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
World world;
Body ballBody;

OrthographicCamera camera;

float cameraMaxY;





@Override
public void create() {
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), false);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();


    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, V_WIDTH, V_HEIGHT);
     cameraMaxY = camera.position.y;



    ballBody = createBall();
    createWalls();
}

private void update() {
    world.step(1f / APP_FPS, 6, 2);

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        ballBody.setLinearVelocity(0, MathUtils.clamp(ballBody.getLinearVelocity().y, 0, 3));
        ballBody.applyForceToCenter(new Vector2(0, 650f), false);
    }

    if (ballBody.getPosition().y * 32 > cameraMaxY) {
        camera.translate(0, (ballBody.getPosition().y * 32) - cameraMaxY);
        camera.update();

        cameraMaxY = camera.position.y;
    }

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.25f, .25f, .25f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    update();

    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined.cpy().scl(32f));
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    world.dispose();
}

private Body createBall() {
    Body body;
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.fixedRotation = true;
    def.position.set(camera.position.x/ 32 + .5f, camera.position.y/ 32);
    def.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y);
    def.gravityScale = 3;
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(0.5f);

    body = world.createBody(def);
    body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);
    return body;

}

private void createWalls() {
    Body body;
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    def.fixedRotation = true;

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(1, 200 / 32);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
        def.position.set(1.01f, i * (200 / 32));
        body = world.createBody(def);
        body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);

        def.position.set(V_WIDTH / 32 - 1, i * (200 / 32));
        body = world.createBody(def);
        body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you reposting the same question?

Comment: I post the same question again, because last time the answer was good, but there was a mistake in it, so I couldn't quit figure out what I should do.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You don't repost duplicate questions. If you want clarification, comment.

Comment: Ok sorry got it, I'm new here. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.25f, .25f, .25f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (ballBody.getPosition().y < camera.position.y){
        destroyBall();
    } else if (ballBody.getPosition().y > camera.position.y + 300){
        camera.position.set(ballBody.getPosition().y - 300);
    }

    update();

    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined.cpy().scl(32f));
}
```

I hope this works. You can write `destroyBall()` method yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But I should probably ask how you would write the destroyBall method, because my way doesn't always work.